# Android intent opens blank PDF even though I used the same path used for saving it

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-external-storage

I'm trying to generate a PDF from a layout with:

```
                PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
                PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(2480, 3508, 0).create();
                PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

                linearview.draw(page.getCanvas());
                document.finishPage(page);

                OutputStream outStream;
                File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "pedido.PDF");

                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    document.writeTo(outStream);
                    document.close();
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "pdf saved to " + getExternalFilesDir(null));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    File myPDF = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "pedido.PDF");
                    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(OrderActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", myPDF);
                    Log.d(TAG, "openPDF: intent with uri: " + uri);
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                }
```

When I run this code, I get a blank PDF opened by the defaut PDF opener. I don't know if it does that because it didn't find the PDF file, but I guess it's the problem, because the PDF is generated correctly. If I go with a file searcher and open the file `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.lucaszanella.venko/files/pedido.PDF` I see the PDF normally.

This is the output I get

```
D/OrderActivity: pdf saved to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.lucaszanella.venko/files
D/OrderActivity: openPDF: intent with uri: content://com.lucaszanella.venko.provider/external_files/Android/data/com.lucaszanella.venko/files/pedido.PDF
```

As you can see, the pdf is saved to the `/storage` folder, but the intent tries to open from `/external_files`. This migth be the problem, but I did everything alrigth, I guess.

**Update:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: Show your paths xml file please.

Comment: @blackapps just updated, please take a look

Comment: That looks ok .

Comment: Make `outStream` be a `FileOutputStream` instead of a plain `OutputStream`. Then, in between the `flush()` and `close()` calls on `outStream`, add `outStream.getFD().sync();`. This ensures all bytes are written to disk before proceeding. Ideally, all this disk I/O would be done on a background thread. Also, note that you do not need the `myPDF` variable, as you could just use `file`. Your `Uri` seems fine. You might also experiment with other PDF viewers, as you may be running into a bug with the viewer that you are trying now.

Comment: @CommonsWare neither of this worked. Can you see that in the log, it saved to `/data/com.lucaszanella.venko/files` but it tried to open from `content://com.lucaszanella.venko.provider/external_files/Android/data/com.lucaszanella.venko/files/pedido.PDF`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that `Uri`, though it would be safer if you got rid of the `myPDF` variable and just used the same `file` that you used for writing. Note that there is no single "defaut PDF opener". I suggest that you try with a few different popular PDF viewers, to see if your problem is tied to the specific one that you have been testing. You might also consider writing an instrumented test to confirm that you can read the PDF from the `Uri` given to you by `FileProvider`.

Comment: @CommonsWare this is what was missing: `                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` even though I don't need permissions to read from the external directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is what was missing:

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`

even though I don't need permissions to read from the external directory.

Comment: I should have thought of that and apologize for missing it. The reason you need that is because without it, the *other app* (PDF viewer) has no rights to read the content associated with the `Uri` in your `Intent`. Note that if you want users to be able to edit the file, you would need to include `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(myPDF);
```

instead of

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(OrderActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", myPDF);
```

Comment: with this I get "exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()"